# Can you make a variable from table that you make in Google Docs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Script and was wondering if I can write something that takes the information I input in a table in Google Docs and make it a variable so that I can transfer it to a Google Sheet and manipulate it the way I need over there.

Comment: It is possible to read data from a google document table and input it into a spreadsheet with google apps script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A Simple Example**

It gets the upper left cell in the first table in the document and sends to cell A1 in a spreadsheet with the provided id and Sheet2

```
function getTableData() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var tables=body.getTables();
  var A1=tables[0].getCell(0, 0).editAsText().getText();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(A1);
}
```

This one gets all the values in the first table.

```
function getTableData() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var tables=body.getTables();
  var A=[];
  for(var i=0;i<tables[0].getNumRows();i++) {
    var r=[];
    for(var j=0;j<tables[0].getRow(i).getNumCells();j++) {
      r.push(tables[0].getCell(i,j).editAsText().getText());
    }
    A.push(r);
  }
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh.getRange(1,1,A.length,A[0].length).setValues(A);
}
```